# Creating Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> dynamically?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sorting, lambda, expression

I wanna create `Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>>` from list of `SortingItems` dynamically.
I mean I wanna create the following expression:

`entity => entity.OrderBy(c => c.Id).ThenBy(c => c.Name).ThenByDescending(c => c.LastName)`

The following is my code :

```
[DataContract]
public class SortingItem
{
    [DataMember]
    public string PropertySelectorString { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public SortingDirectionsEnum SortingDirections { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public enum SortingDirectionsEnum
{
    [EnumMember]
    Descending = 0,

    [EnumMember]
    Ascending = 1
}

public Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> GetSortingFunc<TEntity>()
{
    _entityType = typeof(TEntity);
    _parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(_entityType, "entity");
    _iQueryableParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IQueryable<TEntity>), "f");

    MethodInfo orderByMethodInfo = null;
    Expression resultExpression = null;

    foreach (SortingItem sortingItem in SortingItems)
    {
        MemberExpression memberExpression = GetLeftSide(sortingItem.PropertySelectorString, _entityType, _parameterExpression); // I'm dead sure about working this line

        switch (sortingItem.SortingDirections)
        {
            case SortingDirectionsEnum.Descending:
                orderByMethodInfo = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().First(method => method.Name == "OrderBy" && method.GetParameters().Length == 2).MakeGenericMethod(_entityType, memberExpression.Type);
                if (resultExpression != null)
                    orderByMethodInfo = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().First(method => method.Name == "ThenBy" && method.GetParameters().Length == 2).MakeGenericMethod(_entityType, memberExpression.Type);
                break;

            case SortingDirectionsEnum.Ascending:
                orderByMethodInfo = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().First(method => method.Name == "OrderByDescending" && method.GetParameters().Length == 2).MakeGenericMethod(_entityType, memberExpression.Type);
                if (resultExpression != null)
                    orderByMethodInfo = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().First(method => method.Name == "ThenByDescending" && method.GetParameters().Length == 2).MakeGenericMethod(_entityType, memberExpression.Type);
                break;
        }

        MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression;
        if (resultExpression != null)
            // Exception
            // An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Core.dll
            // Additional information: Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable`1[ConsoleApplication1.User] ThenBy[User,Int32](System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable`1[ConsoleApplication1.User], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[ConsoleApplication1.User,System.Int32]])'
            methodCallExpression = Expression.Call(orderByMethodInfo, _iQueryableParameterExpression, resultExpression, Expression.Lambda(memberExpression, _parameterExpression)); 
        else
            methodCallExpression = Expression.Call(orderByMethodInfo, _iQueryableParameterExpression, Expression.Lambda(memberExpression, _parameterExpression));

        resultExpression = Expression.Lambda(methodCallExpression, _iQueryableParameterExpression);
    }

    Expression<Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>>> lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>>>(resultExpression, _parameterExpression);
    return lambdaExpression.Compile();
}
```

It's OK to create `{f.OrderBy(entity => entity.Id)}` or `{f.ThenBy(entity => entity.Name)}` seperately, but I get exception at the following line

```
methodCallExpression = Expression.Call(orderByMethodInfo, _iQueryableParameterExpression, resultExpression, Expression.Lambda(memberExpression, _parameterExpression));
```

How should I use `Expression.Call` to combine `{f.OrderBy(entity => entity.Id)}` with `{f.ThenBy(entity => entity.Name)}` , .... ?

Comment: Can you explain what you need that for? Possibly there is a much easier solution to your "bigger problem"...

Comment: I created `SortingItems` in client app and send it to service. In Service I wanna create the sorting `func` to use in entity framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you not to write such code, as it's hard to read. I've had to maintain those monsters in the past.

If you're actually interested in the solution, you can download DynamicLINQ, and then your query will be as:

```
public string GetSortCriteria(this SortingItem item){
   return string.Format("{0} {1}", item.PropertySelectorString, 
          item.SortingDirections == SortingDirectionsEnum.Descending ? 
             "DESC" : "ASC");
}

// later: 
var mergedSortCriteria= string.Join(",", 
     SortingItems.Select(item => item.GetSortCriteria());

Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> myFunc = 
      source => source.OrderBy("id " + mergedSortCriteria);
```